# Cant pass string, but can pass #'s to webmethod

Tags: json, parameters, asmx, webmethod

Using extjs in my datagrid setup, I have my proxy api setup as...

```
api: {
read: '/Admin/BillRateData.aspx/Get?rbl=asd'
},
```

and my webmethod as...

```
public static List<Something> Get(string rbl)
```

The response in Firebug is...

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: asd.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromGetRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

And my data being sent looks like this...
When I send letters…

> MyParameter            true
>   _dc     1371570036523 
>   limit     25 
>   page  1 
>   rbl        asd 
>   start     0

When I send a number…

> MyParameter            true
>   _dc     1371570093718
>   limit     25
>   page  1
>   rbl        123
>   start     0

But it wont hit my breakpoint on the webmethod, and JS throws a "read Operation Failed: Internal Server Error". However, if I change the url to "rbl=123", it works fine. It appears to only accept numerical values. What's going on here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting double-quotes around the string value? The "primitive" error you're getting sounds like it's trying to interpret the asd as a variable that's already been defined but it's actually a string literal (but it doesn't know that).  This would also explain why it seems to work for numbers (you don't put double-quotes around numbers).

Comment: I would've never thought of that since it's coming across as a URL...Thanks!